# Using bootstrap side navbar

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

I've implemented bootstrap, if you goto: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix

Im tyring to apply an affix to the left side bar where when I scroll down the side bar stays with the scroll in view. I cannot get this to work. I tried everything. Any ideas or tricks I need to do to get this working?

I tried the data element and javascript way, neither work. I do have the bootstrap.js, bootstrap.cs, and bootstrap-responsive.cs implemented as well.

```html
<div class="container">
    <!-- Docs nav
    ================================================== -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3 bs-docs-sidebar" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200" >

            <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav">
                <li><a href="#AccountId"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>My Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tutorialid"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>My Tutorials</a></li>
                <li><a href="#buttonDropdowns"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>My Articles</a></li>
                <li><a href="#navs"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Help</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="span9">
            <!-- Typography
             ================================================== -->
            <section id="AccountId">
                <div class="page-header">
                     <h1>My Account</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="bs-docs-example">
                     <h3><b>Change Password</b></h3>

                    <div>
                        <label>Current Password</label>
                        <input type="text" />
                        <label>New Password</label>
                        <input type="text" />
                        <label>Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="text" />
                        <br />
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                     <h3><b>Tutorial Settings</b></h3>

                    <div>
                        <label>Current Password</label>
                        <input type="text" />
                        <label>New Password</label>
                        <input type="text" />
                        <label>Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="text" />
                        <br />
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                     <h3><b>Article Settings</b></h3>

                    <div>
                        <label>Current Password</label>
                        <input type="text" />
                        <label>New Password</label>
                        <input type="text" />
                        <label>Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="text" />
                        <br />
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>@* Tutorials *@
            <section id="tutorialid">
                <div class="page-header">
                     <h1>My Tutorials</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="bs-docs-example"></div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you add js file of bootstrap....

Comment: Yes I have added that as well as the cs and the responsive cs

Comment: In what order? The order of your JS is as follows: jQuery goes first, bootstrap plugin pack second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are adding the affix to the `div` while you should add it to the `ul`.

If you inspect the source code of the [Twitter Bootstrap Javascript page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html) that's how they do it.

I tried to do it with your code and it works :)

Comment: I tried that, doesn't work. I don't see where they are setting : data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200" on the <ul>. I right clicked view page source and they don't do it on the ul, actually they don't do it at all.

Comment: And are you including the  <link href="assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet"> also when you do this? I tried it both ways with and without it

Comment: Alright, turns out that using that css I mentioned above was the reason it wasn't working, I wanted that styling so i just went in and deleted anything that had to do with affixing, guess it was overriding it. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Go to the application.js, Line 19.

This will allow you to make custom padding for the sidenav to stop in the appropriate spot that you want it too.